# ffmpeg сохраняет лишние время

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

Пишу установки видос с ютуба. Столкнулся с проблемой что ffmpeg добавляет в начало видео лишние 10 секунд.

Перед запуском ffmpeg получаю URL с помощью данной команды

`yt-dlp -g 'URL of YouTube video'`

Потом пихаю и ffmpeg

`ffmpeg -ss 00:01:10 -i 'URL_1' -ss 00:01:10 -i 'URL_2' -t 00:00:10 -c copy filename.mkv`

Потом конвертирую это в mp4, потому что мой комп отказывается запускать mp4 от ffmpeg. По итогу получаю видос в начале со звуком, но когда проходят лишние 10 секунд начинается видос

Comment: Невозможно разрезать видео в точно указанном месте без перекодирования. Место разрезания переносится к ближайшему ключевому кадру

Comment: Как возможно это исправить? Или это вшито в ffpeg

Comment: Это вшито в фундаментальное устройство видеоформатов. Как исправить — для начала как минимум включить перекодирование, а дальше уже по ситуации

Comment: Спасибо, убрав консервацию всё заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось до банальности прост. Стоило убрать промежуточный слой с конвертацией mkv -> mp4

Comment: Подозреваю, что вы просто замаскировали неровную нарезку. У "лишнего" куска записывается отрицательный timestamp, и некоторые плееры его не воспроизводят и перематывают сразу на положительный timestamp. Проверьте видео в разных плеерах на разных устройствах